# How Environment variable names reflect the structure of an appsettings.json

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 5.0 and I have a Web API app deployed to internal cloud where few settings like DB are controlled via environment variables on the host cloud. In my Startup.cs I have the below code

```
string projectDbConnection = Configuration.GetSection("ProjectDatabaseSettings").GetValue<string>("PROJECT_DB_CONNECTION");
string projectDbName = Configuration.GetSection("ProjectDatabaseSettings").GetValue<string>("PROJECT_DB_NAME");
```

Here as I understand, when running locally in IIS Express it looks for appsettings.`<Environment>`.json and they take precedence over appsettings.json values.

But this app is always connecting to the wrong DB when I deployed to Cloud where I mentioned the `PROJECT_DB_CONNECTION` & `PROJECT_DB_NAME` as Environment variables for the app.
To make the app read from the Environment variables I had to change the above Code in Startup.cs as

```
string projectDbConnection = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PROJECT_DB_CONNECTION");
string projectDbName = Configuration.GetValue<string>("PROJECT_DB_NAME");
```

I am unable to understand the difference between the `GetSection.GetValue` and just `GetValue`  and why I should use `Configuration.GetValue()` to direct app to read from Env variables.

what am I missing and when should we use what?

Answer (score 5):

### Naming of environment variables

There is kind of a **naming convention in the environment variables** for nested appsettings to env vars, [see naming of environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables).
Each element in the hierarchy is separated by a double underscore.

**In your case it would work if you name the env variable: `ProjectDatabaseSettings__PROJECT_DB_CONNECTION`.**

### Config Order

Regarding to [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) there is a order in which the config sources are checked.

- ChainedConfigurationProvider : Adds an existing IConfiguration as a source. In the default configuration case, adds the host configuration and setting it as the first source for the app configuration.
- appsettings.json using the JSON configuration provider.
- **appsettings.Environment.json** using the JSON configuration provider. For example,  appsettings.Production.json and appsettings.Development.json.
- App secrets when the app runs in the Development environment.
- **Environment variables** using the Environment Variables configuration provider.
- Command-line arguments using the Command-line configuration provider.

### The usecase

This is useful when you are developing local using appsettings.json, but run in a cluster or cloud in production where it is more convenient to use environment variables (f.e.: in kubernetes environment variables are set via config maps).