# dotnet entity framework migration: how to set connection string environment variable, with colon, on MacOS

Tags: c#, .net, macos, entity-framework, unix

I'm using EntityFramework in .NET to handle DB migrations.  For example, `dotnet ef migrations list --project My.Project --context MyDbContext`.

However, some of these entity framework commands require a connection string, to connect to the DB and see what's what:

```
    Build started...
    Build succeeded.
    Args are:
    Schema Name: myschema
    Connection string: 
    Connection string not set up. No connection string works when adding a migration (EF compares to the snapshot.cs file) but you will need a connection string to apply a migration.
    Connection string not set up in environment variable: 'ConnectionString:SchemaAdmin'. Set the connection string in the Package Manager Console first: $env:ConnectionString:SchemaAdmin='<replace with connection string>'
```

So I need to set up an environment variable called `ConnectionString:SchemaAdmin` containing the connection string for my DB.

However, this is not easy, since there is a colon in the name of the environment variable:

```
    $ fo:o=bar
    bash: fo:o=bar: command not found
    $ fo\:o=bar; echo $foo
    bash: fo:o=bar: command not found
```

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67699973/11473934 use __ as separator for platform independence.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I found to resolve this was to use AddJsonFile in a builder at Startup (which allows it to find the configuration stored in the appsettings.json file) and then use that to set a private _config variable

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        _config = builder.Build();
    }
```

And then I could set the configuration string as follows:

```
var connectionString = _config.GetConnectionString("DbContextSettings:ConnectionString");
```

Comment: You shouldn‘t explicit add environmental appsettings, use the default Builder … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#appsettingsjson . This will do the trick via naming convention

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  Starting the app is no problem; I can put the variable in json or in the IDE startup settings.  It's only when running the DotNet ef commands from the command line when I have a problem